# How to position a text element to a specific position and resizable in SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, svg-edit

I am creating a rect element based on input values from **textbox**(getting Height,Width,X and Y from textbox).

When rect is created and appended in parent g element. I am creating a **text** element showing the newly created rect number.I positioned this text to **top left** corner of **rect**.

This is my piece of code(not entire only relevant to question).It is called on **onclick** event of button.

```
  //Creating <rect> 
   Rect = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
   Rect.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "rectId");
   Rect.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);   //getting x from textbox
   Rect.setAttributeNS(null, "width", width);   //getting width from 
    textbox
   Rect.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y);   //getting y from textbox
   Rect.setAttributeNS(null, "height", height);  //getting height from 
   textbox
   Rect.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "none");
   grp.appendChild(Rect);


   //Creating <text> for Rect Num
   RectNo = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
   RectNo.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "textNo");
   numTxt = document.createTextNode("RectNum_"+(any number));
   RectNo.appendChild(numTxt);
   grp.appendChild(RectNo);

   scale = (width - (width-13)) / width; //(width of rect)
   posX = x+1;  //(x of rect)
   posY = y+3;  //(y of rect)

   RectNo.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + posX + "," + posY + ") 
   scale(" + scale + ")");
```

Created rect can be of **any size**,so for scaling the text element, I tried above code of transform. But somehow it is not working.What I need is that **no matter how big or small** the rect size is, the **RectNo** text should appear in the **top left-corner of rect** and should get **adjusted(resize height and width)** according to the rect size.

Answer (score 0):

First I get the width of the text:`let txtW = RectNo.getComputedTextLength();`

Next I'm calculating the scale: `scale = (width-13) / txtW;`

I gather that you need a 13 units gap at the end of the text.

Also in the CSS I'm using `text{dominant-baseline:hanging}`, otherwise you'll get the text half outside the rect. I hope it helps.

```js
let x=10,y=10,width=100,height=50,any_number = 3;

//Creating <rect> 
   Rect = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
   Rect.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "rectId");
   Rect.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);   //getting x from textbox
   Rect.setAttributeNS(null, "width", width);   //getting width from textbox
   Rect.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y);   //getting y from textbox
   Rect.setAttributeNS(null, "height", height);  //getting height from textbox
   Rect.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "#d9d9d9");
   grp.appendChild(Rect);


   //Creating <text> for Rect Num
   RectNo = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
   RectNo.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "textNo");
   numTxt = document.createTextNode("RectNum_"+ (Math.random()*100));
   RectNo.appendChild(numTxt);
   
   grp.appendChild(RectNo);

   let txtW = RectNo.getComputedTextLength();

   scale = (width-13) / txtW; 
   posX = x+1;  //(x of rect)
   posY = y+3;  //(y of rect)

   RectNo.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + posX + "," + posY + ")"+"scale(" + scale + ")");
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
text{dominant-baseline:hanging}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <g id="grp"></g>
</svg>
```